# Angular QuickStart project did not work correctly((SystemJS) Unexpected token <)

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I followed [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html) guide for VS2015. When i ran "quick start" project or "tour of heroes" tutorial on google chrome, did not work correctly. ([Angular_QuickStart_Error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TrXq.png)). I researched stackoverflow posts but everyone has taken the error differently.

For Examples:

- [Angular 2 Quickstart: unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387174/angular-2-quickstart-unexpected-token)
- [Angular 2 Quick Start VS 2015 with ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735502/angular-2-quick-start-vs-2015-with-es6)
- ["Unexpected token export" in Angular app with SystemJS and TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154832/unexpected-token-export-in-angular-app-with-systemjs-and-typescript)
- [Kendo UI Angular : (SystemJS) Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576887/kendo-ui-angular-systemjs-unexpected-token)

They are not answer to me.

What can i do?

Comment: If you are using SystemJS and plugin-typescript, you should use `"module": "system"`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad here tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}

I tried you said. I wrote system instead of commonjs but it is not work.

Comment: Can  you add that to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution another way. Follow this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and create new angular cli project.